# what will be primary machine fail of postgresql replication

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I am new at postgresql replication and reading documentations. I looked some replication tutorials. There is one primary machine and multiple stand by machines.

- what will be if primary machine fails? Can I convert stand by machines to primary machine?
- if stand by machines fails, will system gives error? (for example database errors because of connection error.)

I need some fail scenarios answer.

Comment: 1. to failover: `pg_ctl promote` or just create a trigger file on slave 2. what system?.. database server?

Answer (score 0):

- if primary machine fails slaves won't be able to get replication from master. To promote slave a new master, run `pg_ctl promote` ont it or just create a trigger file. If other slaves were configured to stream from this one (cascaded replication) you will have to define latest timeline in recovery.conf.
- if postgres dies on slave, usually you have reason for it in postgres.log. If you ask if master will notice death of any of slaves - no.

If you want some tools, check https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/repmgr